# multiple groupby and get unique count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df1:

```
id period color size rate
1    01    red   12   30
1    02    red   12   30
2    01    blue  12   35
3    03    blue  12   35
4    01    blue  12   35
4    02    blue  12   35
5    01    pink  10   40
6    01    pink  10   40
```

I need to create an index column that is basically a group of color-size-rate and count the number of unique id(s) that have this combination. My output df after transformation should look like this df1:

```
id period color size rate      index     count
1    01    red   12   30    red-12-30     1
1    02    red   12   30    red-12-30     1
2    01    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    3
2    03    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    3
4    01    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    3
4    02    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    3
5    01    pink  10   40    pink-10-40    2
6    01    pink  10   40    pink-10-40    2
```

I am able to get the count but it is not counting "unique" ids but instead , just the number of occurrences.

```
1    01    red   12   30    red-12-30     2
1    02    red   12   30    red-12-30     2
2    01    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    4
2    03    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    4
4    01    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    4
4    02    blue  12   35    blue-12-35    4
```

This is wrong as it is not actually grouping by id to count unique ones.

Appreciate any pointers in this direction.

Adding an edit here as my requirement changed:
The count need to also be grouped by 'period' ie my final df should be:

```
index       period   count
red-12-30    01        1
red-12-30    02        1
blue-12-35   01        2
blue-12-35   03        1
blue-12-35   02        1
pink-10-40   01        2
```

Solution: from @anky:
When I try adding another groupby['period'], I am getting dimension mismatch error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, editing now , thanks @anky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try aggregating a `join` for creating the index column, then group on the same and get `nunique` using `groupby+transform`

```
idx = df[['color','size','rate']].astype(str).agg('-'.join,1)
out = df.assign(index=idx,count=df.groupby(idx)['id'].transform('nunique'))
```

---

```
print(out)

   id  period color  size  rate       index  count
0   1       1   red    12    30   red-12-30      1
1   1       2   red    12    30   red-12-30      1
2   2       1  blue    12    35  blue-12-35      3
3   3       3  blue    12    35  blue-12-35      3
4   4       1  blue    12    35  blue-12-35      3
5   4       2  blue    12    35  blue-12-35      3
6   5       1  pink    10    40  pink-10-40      2
7   6       1  pink    10    40  pink-10-40      2
```

Comment: Hi anky, I just edited the OP to include what I am trying to do. i need to add another groupby['period']. Any suggestions for what I can try? Thank you.

Comment: @savi i think you are looking for `df.groupby([idx,'period'],sort=False)['id'].nunique().reset_index(name='count')` or if you can do away with the index this is plain `df.groupby(['color','size','rate','period'])['id'].nunique().reset_index()`

Comment: No, I need the index column as i am creating a pivot_table next and then a heatmap